# Which Approach Better Between JSon DataType and @ElementCollection

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

A product specification varies for the specification field name among different products. One approach is the following:

```
@Entity
class Product {

  @ElementCollection
  private Map<String, String> specs = new HashMap<>();

  ...
}
```

The other approach is to use the JSon datatype in PostgreSQL.

```
class SpecData {

  private Map<String, String> data;

  ...
}

@Entity
class Product {

  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  private SpecData specs;

}
```

along with a UserType and DataConvertor classes.

The first approach requests another table while the second one doesn't. Is the second better than the first one?

Comment: Fail to see how a non-portable proprietary method could ever be "better" than a portable standard method ... FWIW. Alternatively you use @AttributeConverter ... and stay portable

Comment: Thanks. That definitely is another approach.

Comment: DB portability isn't a big concern, however. I likely won't move to another DB, PostgreSQL also offers a geo data type which can be useful for geo data related functionalities in the app.

Comment: Portability is not just DB, it is also JPA provider. Your option 2 is totally Hibernate specific.